# App crashes when but still populates realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My app crashes when I populate 2 children simultaenously but the data still goes to the database. The first child is named Appointment and the second child is AppDate.

```
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Appointment apps = new Appointment(tname.getText().toString(), data1, tdate.getText().toString(), ttime.getText().toString(), taptype.getText().toString(), apstat.getText().toString(),dateid);

        table_user.child(data1).setValue(apps);

        table_user2.child(dateid).setValue(dateid);
        submission success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTjDc.png)
 [and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OII7h.png)

Comment: Please add crash log

Comment: 05-16 15:08:39.702 1636-1691/system_process E/MountService: Failed to unmount appfuse.
05-16 15:10:59.950 3041-3536/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
05-16 15:10:59.950 3041-3536/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
05-16 15:10:59.950 3041-3536/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
05-16 15:11:00.225 3041-3536/com.google.android.gms.unstable

Comment: No this is not the correct log , post complete log . Do not post it in comments , edit you question and add complete error log .